# Resharper Dataflow analysis

Tags: c#, resharper, dataflow

I'm using the TPL Dataflow library extensively, and really like the Used-By feature of R#. What would be nice is to look at the used by of a method which is the target of an ITargetBlock (Action block most likely) and return a list of the ITargetBlock.Post calls in addition to any direct method calls. Like-wise when you control click (go to declaration) on ITargetBlock.Post, it should take you directly to the destination method of the action block, not to the definition of the ITargetBlock.

```
ActionBlock<T> ab = new ActionBlock<T>(FuncCall, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {TaskScheduler = taskScheduler});
```

Setup the action block

```
ab.Post(NewVal);
```

Post a new value to the action block, which will then be passed to the FuncCall method - Control clicking on ab / ab.Post should take you to the method below.

```
private void FuncCall(T parameter)
{
    //Do work
}
```

Calling find usages on the above method should take you to ab.Post(NewVal), not to the ab definition.

I'm wondering if there is any way to configure this with resharper. I imagine it is doable by writing a custom plugin, but I thought others may be running into this problem, and wanted to see if there was a simple way to achieve this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write a custom plug-in as the information to use would be different for each type of wrapper; `Action`, `Func`, `ActionBlock`, etc...

It might be a convenience (which is what much of R# is about) but it'd only save you one keystroke.

In your example, F12 on `ab` to GoToImplementation then Ctrl+Click on `FuncCall`